# share image from drawable in android

Tags: android, share, drawable

i want share some image from res/drawable folder in my program . 
this is my code :

```
String _ImageFile = "android.resource://" + getResources().getResourceName(R.id.mypic).replace(":", "/");
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(_ImageFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

it's work with Instagram but not work with Email or Viber . 
when i select share with email , attached successfull but send file without any extention . 
what is my wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this line in your coding

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

instead of

```
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 2):

Other applications cannot see/read/write your private files in internal memory. 'Files' from res/drawable are also private. You have to copy them first to a place where external apps can 'reach' them. To external memory for instance.

Answer (score 0):

***Try*** -

```
String _ImageFile = "android.resource://" + getResources().
getResourceName(resID).replace(":", "/");
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(_ImageFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

***For Viber -***

```
String _ImageFile = "android.resource://" + getResources().
getResourceName(resID).replace(":", "/");
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(_ImageFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setPackage("com.viber.voip"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the image URI for drawable Images, do like this -

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"
          +R.drawable.image_name);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: @MiladCoder - Check the update. You need to use package for viber which is `"com.viber.voip".`

Comment: i have't problem with Viber Intent . but i have problem with image extention . i guess send image to viber without any extention .

Comment: @MiladCoder - Did you tried the way I mentioned ? Again you try with `com.viber.voip` and also set the intent type as `image/*`.

Comment: i want send file to all of sharing Intent . your code navigate to JUST viber app . and not work yet...

Comment: @MiladCoder - Your first comment was for `Viber` with the intention that rest other things are working. So my second update in the code was for `Viber`. What is not working. Please mention.

Comment: when i click on share icon . appear intent sharing with some app . and select one app to share . this code just working with Instagram . not working whit viber or email or.....

Comment: @MiladCoder - Are you sure that your image is a valid jpg file. Are you able to open it manually ? This code is just like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855941/share-image-does-not-work-in-viber-and-facebook. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) and mind this:

Note: Some e-mail applications, such as Gmail, expect a String[] for extras like EXTRA_EMAIL and EXTRA_CC, use putExtra(String, String[]) to add these to your intent.

So, for example add the additional extras like this:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, “Some Subject Line”);
```

And consider which extras your target applications expect.

Comment: i have problem with image extention . when i select email , attach file without any extention . and same problem in viber

Comment: Then browse this issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304082/gmail-attachment-and-custom-extension
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870570/custom-mime-type-ignored-in-gmail-app

Comment: use less url . you know what ? i have problem with image extention for sharing...